# How can I get Polymorphic behavior with collections of custom polymorphic types?

Tags: c#, collections, polymorphism, abstraction

I have a Superclass, `Super` with a Subclasses `SubA`

```
public class Super{}

public class SubA : Super{}
```

I want to have an interface that defines some actions on collections of `Super`.

```
public interface IDoer
{
    List<Super> GetObjects();
    void SaveObjects(List<Super> items);
}
```

So basically, I want to be able to polymorphically pass around collections of `Supers`, but `List<SubA>` is not a `List<Super>`. So my subADoer doesn't implement the IDoer.

```
public class SubADoer : IDoer
{
    public List<SubA> GetObjects{ return new SubA()}
    public void SaveObjects(List<SubA> items){//save}
}
```

How can I abstract Lists (or some other collection type) of my objects that sort of mirror the relationship between the types that compose them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use generics, like this:

```
public interface IDoer<T> where T : Super
{
    List<T> GetObjects();
    void SaveObjects(List<T> items);
}

public class SubADoer : IDoer<SubA>
{
    public List<SubA> GetObjects()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void SaveObjects(List<SubA> items)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was missing :-)

Comment: @ArcherBird note that question highlighted need for "polymorphism" which really not present in this option... `IDoer<TDerived>` will continue being *sibling* of `IDoer<TBase>`...